# How to know php script is request in HTTPS not HTTP?

Tags: php

I have checked all $_SERVER member var, still don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do print_r($_SERVER);
=> you can see this. [HTTPS] => on

Comment: I don't have this var in my $_SERVER, why ?

Answer (score 7):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')
    // do your stuff here...
```

Comment: is there some time that it will be `!= 'off'` __AND__ `!= 'on'`?

Comment: Yes. IIS with ISAPI. See Mauris' answer.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That comment was actually the right answer, but not to your question, @quack. I don't know of any other case. However, as Mauris' wrote, IIS sets the value to 'off' when using ISAPI which is why the second part of the condition is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

`$_SERVER['HTTPS']` - from http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
>
> **Note**: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'
```

**upd:** and `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443//80 for http`